# How do I install Win2D in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, package-management

I am trying to install Win2D in visual studio. I ran the the following in the nuget package manager console:

```
PM> Install-Package Win2D
```

I get the following error:

```
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Win2D 0.0.10'. You are trying to install this package into a project that 
targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are 
compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Win2D
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I just installed Visual Studio Community 2013 today so I should the newest version. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is the other way around.

> You are trying to install this package into a project that  targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are 
>   compatible with that framework.

This lists two facts:

1. Your project is .NET 4.5 based.
2. The package ('Win2D 0.0.10') is incompatible with .NET 4.5.

Therefore you need to target a compatible version of .NET or ask the package's author to support it.

Comment: Not sure if you need a newer or older .NET; make sure you have any updates to .NET (eg. 4.5.1, 4.5.2), as well as that the project targets that before trying out older versions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems they only target WinRT (metro / phone apps). You won't be able to use it on regular desktop projects.

https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D/issues/208